# MANIFEST file class path is ignored

Tags: java, maven, jvm, classpath, manifest.mf

i created a maven project (test) in eclips then exported it as jar file (test.jar) where the MANIFEST file include the class path to the jars referenced in the test project (dependancies from POM.XML), now i want to use this jar file inside a new project (test 2), hence, i added (test.jar) to the lib folder and to the build path of of (test 2 project), the problem is that i received no class definition exception for any of the classes inside the jars of test.jar, like if the calss-path inside the MANIFEST file is ignored
the POM.xml of the first project (test)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sts</groupId>
    <artifactId>STSIdentityManagement</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.tirasa.connid</groupId>
            <artifactId>connector-framework-contract</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <!-- <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix> -->
                            <!-- <mainClass>test.org.Cliente</mainClass> -->
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the pom.xml of the second project,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jo.egov.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>MoICTRegistration</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Search Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>  
         <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>  
         <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>  
         <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>  
    </properties>  
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>  
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>  
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
             <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>         
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>  
            <version>${spring.version}</version>  
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.8.2</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>  
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.tirasa.connid</groupId>
            <artifactId>connector-framework-contract</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>  
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>  
        <plugins>  
            <plugin>  
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
                <configuration>  
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>  
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>  
                </configuration>  
            </plugin>  
      </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom files? Is the second project also a maven project?

Comment: yes the second project is also maven

Comment: Please edit your question and add those pom files.

Comment: how can i add them in a scroll bar, they are very large

Comment: You can add code blocks that are automatically scrollable.